# MySQL Tables Disappearing

Tags: mysql, innodb

We're having some issues of tables "magically" disappearing.

Here is the log file leading to the point of what seems to be the point of the table disappearing:

```
131103  9:08:39  InnoDB: Error: table 'acc235_wrdp3/ptjujv_wfNet404s'
131103  9:08:45  InnoDB: Error: table 'acc235_wrdp3/ptjujv_wfNet404s'
InnoDB: open the tablespace file './acc235_wrdp3/ptjujv_wfNet404s.ibd'!
131103  9:37:16  InnoDB: error: space object of table 'acc235_wrdp3/ptjujv_wfNet404s',
InnoDB: open the tablespace file './acc235_wrdp3/ptjujv_wfNet404s.ibd'!
131103  9:37:16  InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table acc235_wrdp3/ptjujv_wfNet404s
table acc235_wrdp3/ptjujv_wfNet404s does not exist.
```

`mysql --version`
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: After how long did it happen ? Can you access as mysql user the path where database is located ? Is it protected by kerberos or something similar ? {Maybe a token is expired}

Comment: Not sure how long after, looking at the log, looks like it disappeared 30 minutes after the initial error.

MySQL does have access.

Comment: did you play at all with ndbd and --initial parameters ? Do you run mysql locally or on a cluster ?